# How to have a constant field inside a object

Tags: oracle, plsql

to test the code: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1be9f3d406df287afd874ad5dfc94cfc

I would like to have constant field inside a object. I can do that with a package but I haven't succeeded to do that with an object. Why?

```
create type a as object(
  a  integer
) --OK

create type  as object(
  b constant  integer :=1
)
```

> ORA-02302: invalid or missing type name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`CREATE TYPE` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TYPE-statement.html#GUID-389D603D-FBD0-452A-8414-240BBBC57034) does not allow it:

> #### object_type_def ::=
>
> [image: OBJECT type syntax]
>
> #### datatype ::=
>
> [image: DATATYPE syntax]

Nowhere does it say that you can use the [`CONSTANT` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/constant-declaration.html#GUID-C6DA65F8-3F0C-43F3-8BC6-231064E8C1B6).

---

As an alternative, you can create an attribute and set it to a value in a user-defined constructor:

```sql
CREATE TYPE test IS OBJECT(
  a  NUMBER,
  pi NUMBER,
  
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION test(
    SELF IN OUT NOCOPY test,
    a NUMBER
  ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
```

with the type body:

```sql
CREATE TYPE BODY test IS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION test(
    SELF IN OUT NOCOPY test,
    a NUMBER
  ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.a  := a;
    SELF.pi := 3.14159;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT test(1).a, test(1).pi
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TEST(1).A | TEST(1).PI |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 3.14159 |

However, that does not make the value a constant and it can still be set to something else:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_obj TEST := TEST(1);
BEGIN
  v_obj.pi := 4; -- For large circles!
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_obj.a || ', ' || v_obj.pi );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1, 4
> ```

As long as you have a policy of never changing the value then it will be the default from the user-defined constructor; if someone breaks that policy then...

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=345c3841b330a1946e368e244b9dbb80)*